# show batch class DMFStagingWriter in task list

Tags: class, task, batch-processing, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm playing with DIXF and following Alex's blog http://ax2012aifintegration.blogspot.com/2014/05/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-file_4600.html?showComment=1405542006070#c2497509467713291887

I'm stuck on creating a batch job that has two tasks -- one for getting data from staging table and another for exporting teh data from staging table to a flat file.

The first task requires that I invoke DMFStagingWriter class. The AX-shipped version doesn't have the canGoBatchJournal set to true; so the class doesn't show in the task list. I overrode that method and returned a value of true. I compiled the class and generated an incremental CIL. However, when I try to use that class in the batch task list, it doesn't show. If I type it in, AX says it is an invalid class.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution. It was a matter of simply getting out of Ax and coming back in to resolve the issue.